# Creating table with data records as a form

Tags: php, sql, database, admin

I have this code which outputs **code1, code2** as a string.

I need:

1. To print this on the screen in a **table**
2. Create possibility for the admin to ***add*** or ***delete*** those codes.(each record needs to be a ***form*** with the ***submit*** button).
3. The space for adding new ***codes*** need to be at the bottom of the table which lists all the codes

**Code:**

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "////";
$db_pass = "////";
$db_name = "////";

// Establish a connection with the db
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if($conn->connect_error) {
  die('connection failed');
}

$results = $conn->query('SELECT value FROM dcodes');

if($results->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$row_str=implode(',', $row);
$row_arr[]=$row_str;

}  array_unique($row_arr);
}
$new_row_str = implode(',', $row_arr);
echo $new_row_str;


$conn->close();
```

Please help me.I don't know how to realize this but must finish this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTML for the table

Comment: If you need a `HTML` table, that Manage all data I suggest you using `DataTable` tools(`https://datatables.net`), it is a useful and easy to use tools. you need to read some about it in given link.